# same view, same url path, identical content, but different categories

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Not sure if this is a bug or not, but it's giving me a headache already.
When I add new content on my D7 website, an article in this case I'm facing a strange behavior. Each article has its own "category" (taxonomy). In the article content type I've created a **field_article_category** and the widget is a Select list. Because I want the possibility for an article to have one or more categories, I had to change the settings of the **field_article_category**, of **Number of values** to *Unlimited* so I can select multiple values when I add a new article content.

The problem is when I add the content with at least 2 categories selected, it does create a view with the same article twice. It has same path, same title, same image, same content, only the categories are different. (see photo attached)[image]

And the result I'd like to have is to have one single article with two different categories.

I already tried to disable the caching of the article view, but it does not help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should show your views configuration.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! Here is a link to an image with my views config - https://imgur.com/a/g8L34gZ